# Eclipse RCP DirectoryDialog not showing initial directory

Tags: eclipse, dialog, rcp

Im using a DirectoryDialog like this:

```
public static String showDialog(Composite parent, String path)
{
    log.debug("Showing submission directory dialog");
    Shell shell = parent.getShell();
    DirectoryDialog dialog = new DirectoryDialog(shell);
    dialog.setFilterPath(path);
    return dialog.open();
}
```

Works fine, but the view is not showing the directory provided by the path. It is selected but not shown:

[image: One]

Should be something like this:
[image: Two]

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Verify that path is `not null or empty`.

Comment: The path is neither null nor empty. As I wrote, the path is selected but not displayed correct.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO it is not possible. These are native dialogs of underlying OS, so the behaviour of these dialogs may change one OS to other.

Automatic scrolling to the selected folder may not possible.

**Also check whether it works:** Open DirectoryDialog and hide the hidden folders, so automatically the filter folder will be visible.

Comment: open the notepad and click on open file then in the window you can customize the view like show in list, details, add or remove column etc. Right click on this area check some option here. I am on Ubuntu not able to guide you exactly with screenshot. Check this image http://i.imgur.com/SftoFYe.jpg

Comment: Ah you mean Windows specific. This doesn't change anything at all, but thanks for your effort